# Command line app does not exit if Simple Injector Verify method is used

Tags: simple-injector

I have a windows command line application that uses Simple Injector. The registration of the services and resolving works fine.

But if I use `container.Verify()` after registering all the services, the windows command line terminal does not close. I don't see any exit code in the Visual Studio output  window also.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. Try running outside of Visual Studio.

Comment: I ran the command line ```exe``` outside of *Visual Studio 2017*. I see the same behavior where the app is not exiting.

Comment: In that case you probably do something in a constructor that keeps the process alive. Like spinning a thread for example.

Comment: I don't think there is any issue with the Simple Injector method ```container.Verify()```. In my code, I'm registering a service that consumes RabbitMQ (a third party library). The Simple Injector ```container``` is passed to that third party service. I don't know if that third party service is holding up the ```container```.

Comment: I should call ```Environment.Exit((int) 0);``` in my command line app to terminate the app. There is nothing wrong in the third party library doing with the container causing this. It registers some interfaces. Is the ```container.Verify()``` method doing anything which can take a while to release all the objects? I tried ```container.Dispose();``` which also does not work.